# SSMS specific pages and how to get there

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I am trying to navigate my way around SSMS, and I was wondering what the following three page types are called and how to navigate there:

1. Editing a table. Has these icons:

[image]

2. Editing/writing a query. Has these icons:

[image]

3. "Building" a query by selecting fields in one or more tables:

[image]

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what you're asking. Those are toolbars are are shown/hidden depending on what you have open in the main window (e.g., when designing a table, it opens the 'table designer' toolbar). You can right click on a blank area in the toolbar area to see and open/close them manually, but they often won't make sense (also have greyed out buttons) if you aren't doing the relevant tasks. You can mouse over the buttons (especially the picture ones) to get a text name for what the buttons are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To edit a table, right click on it and select "design"
2. to edit/write a query, click "new query" in tool bar
3. To build a query by designing it, select Query > Design query in editor from the menu
   [image]

Comment: thanks, that answers the first and second. For the third one it seems always greyed-out. How do I access that? It seems it only works if I click "Edit first 200 rows" from a table...

Comment: You should be able to choose query designer at any time: